# My Maximum Processor Speed states 2.7GHZ but only runs at 0.86GHZ - it was running at 3.02GHZ yesterday?

Tags: cpu, speed, ghz

Normally it runs at 0.86GHZ at max, even though it can run up to 2.7GHZ.

Yesterday I closed a lot of tasks/processes through the task manager, not sure what I was closing, but it seemed to have worked in allowing the processor speed to reach up to maximum if not more.

One process which is bugging me, is WMI Provider Host. This one I some how got to close, and stayed closed for a good couple hours, which I believed enabled maximum speed to work, but I am not 100% sure.

I'm not that tech savvy, so layman terms would be appreciated.

Power Options are both 100% Minimum/Maximum.

'Adjust for best performance' is enabled.

How do I get it to run up to maximum speed, something is clearly stopping it.

It worked yesterday, although normally it has never been up to maximum speed not even when I bought it, that was 2-3 years or so now.

I'm a gamer and this is really bugging me, it was working perfectly now completely and utterly disgraceful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank You Ramhound, for editing my pictures, wouldn't let me without 10+ reputation.

Comment: Did you research first?  Hint power savings lowers processor speed when not needed.  Do a stress test that actually needs the CPU to see the max speed.  AMD Cool N' Quiet http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/processor-power-management,2453.html

Answer (score 2):

The A6-4400M APU runs at certain cpu-clock-speeds according to the processing demands of running applications to save energy and minimize heat emission. If the utilization is low it can go below the standard clock-speed (<2.7 GHz), if it is high it can go beyond (up to 3.2 GHz). If you get too much heat emission, e.g. while playing in bed and occluding the fan vents, the clock-speed gets throttled down without regard to the demanded processing power. If your game is actually running, the cpu-clock is most likely between 2.7 and 3.2 GHz as intended.
But on top of that, the overall computing power of your system is pretty low regarding actual games.

Comment: It is important to note that the stepping happens very quickly, so if you have a full-screen game running and you close it, the CPU frequency will probably drop down to idle before you can get back to the desktop to check it